# What are the main differences between Ubuntu Desktop and Ubuntu Touch?

Tags: ubuntu-touch

Now that Ubuntu for phones is mature enough and established, can someone intimately familiar can explain what are the main differences between the two.

Where the two diverge to the point of being incompatible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's not much different on the terms of the layout, also you still have command line accessibility, however the biggest difference in the apps, not all apps available on Computer are available on mobile and Vice Versa. Another major difference is the ease of use with HTML 5 and easily being able to turn your web page into an Ubuntu touch app. The mobile SDK does a lot of the work for you.

Answer (score 3):

The desktop currently runs Unity 7 on top of Compiz and X.org

Mobile runs Unity 8 on top of Mir.

Almost everything else is the same.  Soon, desktop will also be Unity 8 and Mir, then there will be no difference.